# Blackberry Menu from native blackberry application

Tags: events, blackberry, menu

I have an application that inserts an ApplicationMenuItem into the native blackberry contacts menu. I can get this to work just fine. Now my question is how would I change or remove that ApplicationMenuItem based on the contact that i am highlighted on? Would I need to use a GlobalEventListener? I assume overriding makeMenu can only be done for menus on my own screens and not the native contacts screen?

Comment: Hi @chrishawn, I've updated my answer according to some new info I got from rim, then I realized you don't get notified about it... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We wanted to do something similar and were told by RIM (during the last BB Dev Con) that currently this is not possible, you cannot display menu items based on the highlighted item in a native application. Sorry.. :)

**Update:** in the [New England Blackberry developers meeting](http://www.meetup.com/New-England-BlackBerry-Developers/) last Tuesday, Mike Kirkup mentioned they are actively working to add this functionality but there's still no estimate for when it will be ready. Also, I guess it will be added to future versions and backward compatibility will have to be considered...